# OpenCV made by Cmake does not contain any libaries

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am trying to setup OpenCV for Visual Studio 2015, x64, in windows.
I have followed [this](https://hemprasad.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/opencv-2-4-10-complete-installation-in-windows-8-1/) guide to get OpenCV up and running, however after the CMake Part, i am not sure if everything has gone well.

1- my build file does not contain any lib folder

2- i am confused as where should i set the environment variable for it

3- I assume in visual studio i have to set path for the libraries, but i 
don't see any in my build
4- my include folder has a weird install file

pic1: here is a picture of my OpenCV file that cMake built

[image]

bin folder is empty

pic2:include folder contents
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake does not build your library. It sets your build *environment*, such as designating the install directory for the OpenCV.

So you need to actually build your OpenCV library, then you'll have your include and lib files at the place you've designated as the install directory (*cmake_install_prefix* in the CMake option).

If you've done your CMake step successfully, you can build your OpenCV by building ALL_BUILD project in your Visual Studio project explorer, and building INSTALL project after that.

Comment: Thank you for your response, there is two Install files, one in the include file, and one in the main folder. does it matter which one i use?

Comment: If you open your OpenCV solution with Visual Studio(it seems you have OpenCV.sln file in your main folder), there will be projects named ALL_BUILD and INSTALL. Build those.

Comment: Thank you kind sir